# ROS Subscriber Listner String Message

Tags: ros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

this is the subscriber node from ros tutorials:

```
void chatterCallback(const std_msgs::String::ConstPtr& msg) 
{
  ROS_INFO("I heard: [%s]", msg->data.c_str());
}
```

My string array consists of msg which is shown in image, Now i need to access a particular element in the msg (message consists first time and next CAN message, I want to use particularly CAN.ID whic is arrays second element)
any suggestion. thanks in advance

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/253197/ros-subscriber-listner-string-message/) by [newbieros](https://answers.ros.org/users/23682/newbieros/) on ROS Answers with karma: 31 on 2017-01-28

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2017-01-28**:
First: `std_msgs/String` is a very bad choice for this, as it has no semantics whatsoever. a `String` is not the same as a CAN frame, even though both consists of a 'string' of bytes.

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2017-01-28**:
Second: if possible, see if you can reuse something that already exists. It could save you a lot of effort.

Perhaps [ros_canopen](http://wiki.ros.org/ros_canopen) can do what you need.

**Comment by [newbieros](https://answers.ros.org/users/23682/newbieros/) on 2017-01-28**:
I am using some CAN USB interface, where I am using those receive and transmit nodes which are already existed for this hardware type. So the message that they have used here is std_msgs/String.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

C++'s `std::string` class provides an indexing operator implementation that lets you access individual characters in the string. See [std::string::operator[]](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/string/string/operator%5B%5D/) for details.

In your particular case, you could do something like:

```
size_t my_index = ...;
char the_byte = msg->data[my_index];
```

Now `the_byte` contains the `char` at position `my_index` in `msg->data` (which is of type `std::string` ([wiki/msg](http://wiki.ros.org/msg))).

As I wrote in my comment on your OP though: `std_msgs/String` is really not a good message to use for interfacing with CAN wrappers (or for storing byte buffers in, period).

---

Originally posted by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) with karma: 86574 on 2017-01-29

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2017-01-29**:
Note btw that this is not something that is ROS specific at all. It's a basic C++ question.